# Are Firefox sync bookmarks available via a web based interface?

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

I know Firefox has a built in way of syncing bookmark across multiple machines.

The problem is: I'm not necessarily using my own PC or laptop. Therefore I'm not really supposed to change settings.

Is there a way I can add / retrieve these bookmarks via a web based interface?

Answer (score 1):

No. Currently, the only features available through [Firefox Sync's web interface](https://account.services.mozilla.com/) are the following administrative actions:

> **Account Settings**
>
> - Change your password
> - Delete your account
>
> **Sync Settings**
>
> - Clear your Sync data
> - Request a quota increase

However, If you are using a Windows PC, you can download and use [Firefox Portable](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable) as a workaround to access your bookmarks.

Answer (score 1):

The answer really seems to be No, at this time. Though, two things I noticed:

1. It should be technically possible, as something like that works for some people who are using [CloudFox](http://cloudfox.codeplex.com/), which is a Windows Phone application with the desired functionality.
2. I'm very satisfied with a workaround I have found in the Diigo Toolbar extension. In it's setting, you make it to save bookmarks both to the nice Diigo social bookmarking cloud and into your local bookmarks at the same time. That way, you can find your bookmarks at your Diigo page wherever you go (including phone etc.) while you also have your bookmarks locally and on all the computers where you set up the Firefox Sync.

   The only thing you have to change in your workflow is to save all the bookmarks (which you want to have accessible anywhere from Diigo) througn the Diigo button, but I don't find any problem with that.